# Excel vba array of objects with matrix

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to create an array of objects. All objects are from a same class.
I want each object to have a matrix (two dimension array). But I can't make it right.

I have this in my module1:

```
Public Arr As Variant
```

the `clsStudent` class is:

```
Public ID As Integer
Public Name As String
Public Teacher As String
Private Matrix(6, 14) As String
```

And this is in my Sheet1 sub:

```
Dim i, k As Integer
i = 20
ReDim Arr(0 To (i)) As clsStudent ' array with students size
For k = 0 To i
    Set Arr(k) = New clsStudent
Next k
Arr(0).ID = 123
Arr(0).Matrix(0, 0).Value = "123"  'error here
```

The last line gives me an error:

> object doesn't support this property or method

I tried changing the matrix to:

```
Public Matrix(6,14) as String
```

but I get this error:

> Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and Declare statments not allowed as Public members of object modules

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating properties to access the private Matrix field in your class instance.  Properties allow you to define the public interface to private class fields.  Keep the matrix private but give it a unique name like:

```
Private pMatrix(6, 14) As String
```

The unique name allows you to use the more intuitive name in your `Get` and `Let` properties.  These properties allow you to define read and write interfaces respectively and might look like this:

```
Public Property Let Matrix(i As Integer, j As Integer, value As String)
    pMatrix(i, j) = value
End Property

Public Property Get Matrix(i As Integer, j As Integer) As String
    Matrix = pMatrix(i, j)
End Property
```

You can place those directly below the field declarations in your class module.

Finally, you can remove the `.Value` method from your Worksheet Subroutine, the `pMatrix` field does not contain this method.  The `=` tells the compiler that you wish to call the `Let` property which sends the two property parameters `(0, 0)` as the first two parameters in the property `i` and `j` and the value on the right hand side of the assignment as the third parameter `value`.

My modified code is listed entirely below:

```
****clsStudent****
Option Explicit

Public ID As Integer
Public Name As String
Public Teacher As String
Private pMatrix(6, 14) As String

Public Property Let Matrix(i As Integer, j As Integer, value As String)
    pMatrix(i, j) = value
End Property

Public Property Get Matrix(i As Integer, j As Integer) As String
    Matrix = pMatrix(i, j)
End Property

****clsStudent****

****Module1****
Option Explicit

Public Arr As Variant
****Module1****

****Sheet1****
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim i As Integer, k As Integer
i = 20

ReDim Arr(0 To (i)) As clsStudent ' array with students size

For k = 0 To i
    Set Arr(k) = New clsStudent
Next k

Arr(0).ID = 123
Arr(0).Matrix(0, 0) = "123"  'no error here anymore

Debug.Print Arr(0).Matrix(0, 0)

End Sub
****Sheet1****
```

For info, the `Module1` codes is not neccessarily required for this to work.

***Edited to include shA.t's comment regarding variable declaration

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a public 2D array I suggest you to use this methods:

```
Public Function getMatrix(Bound1 As Integer, Bound2 As Integer) As String
    getMatrix = Matrix(Bound1, Bound2)
END Function
```

and

```
Public Sub setMatrix(Bound1 As Integer, Bound2 As Integer, mValue As String)
    Matrix(Bound1, Bound2) = mValue
END Function
```

---

> **Out-Note:**
>   `Dim i, k As Integer` is equivalent of `Dim i As Variant, k As Integer` and is not equivalent of `Dim i As Integer, k As Integer`.

Use `Dim i As Integer, k As Integer`

Comment: I think im almost there thanks to you. im missing one thing, in my sheet i believe im suppose to type now: Arr(0).setmatrix(0,0,"123") but it says expected =